# Using cucumber to run different tagged features sequentially

Tags: cucumber, page-object-gem

I'm attempting to run tagged features in the order that they are submitted.

example:

I have tests that i'd like to run in a specific order (@test1, @test2, @test3). After looking at the cucumber documentation is looks like i'm only able to run them in an and/or option like

> cucumber features/*.feature --t @test1; cucumber features/*.feature --t @test2; cucumber features/*.feature --t @test3;

but this prevents me from having a single report which contains all of the results.

Is there anyway which I can run these tests in their respective order and have all of the results contained in the same report?

Comment: Can you elaborate the reason why your test must be run in a specific order?

Answer (score 2):

If you put the tests that have to run in a specific order in a feature file together cucumber will run them in the order they are given.  As this will be in your normal test run it should all show up in the same report.

But it might be worth looking into why your tests are dependant on each other and if there is a way to remove this dependancy as it is generally bad practice to have it.